# Iputils arping works good with ethernet devices but not with wifi devices

Tags: linux, networking, router, ethernet, arp

1. I am developing an application for an embedded device to check whether a particular network device present in the local network (192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254) is alive.
2. Initially I was using ping to check the alive status. If I received a ping reply the device is alive or else it is not alive. But then some of my devices block ICMP requests.
3. I read about Address Resource Protocol and how ARP requests are not blocked by most of the network devices. Hence I moved to arping to check the alive status.
4. When I arping a device which is connected over ethernet to my home network, I am getting Unicast replies from that device
5. But when I try the same with devices that are connected over wifi, the arping takes almost 5-10 mins to receive the first unicast reply for its ARP request. Sometimes I receive no reply even if the device I am arpinging is powered ON and connected to the network

I am running Linux on my embedded device and the device is resource constrained.

My motive is to check the alive status of every device that is connected over ethernet to my home network. The devices may or may not have a firewall. Most of the devices run Linux and some run Windows.

I am a beginner in networking. Any detailed explanation in understanding how arping works and whether it would be suitable for my use case would be highly helpful.

Thanks.